# Split a javascript string between two HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a javascript string which contains a HTML code to be loaded into my app. The issue I am finding is that the string has a bunch of tags in the head tags which just displays as text at the top of the content. How can I remove all the content of the string bar whats between the two body tags? 
E.g.

```
<html><head><meta>...</meta><style>...</style></head><body><div>...</div></body></html>
```

Needs changing to:

```
<div>...</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: `document.body.innerHTML = ''`?

Comment: post some code what's in your string ? what you want to retreive ? and what have you tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use code below but you better change the service that returns html result.

```
var s = "<HTML><head><meta><head><body>YOUR HTML</body></html>"
var body = "<body>";
var bodyEnd = "</body>";
var res = s.substring(s.indexOf(body)+body.length,s.indexOf(bodyEnd));
```

Comment: I guess you should use the bodyEnd variable in the last indexOf instead of the "</body>" string. or do not use the variable at all